Confusing statement in Sutton-Barto on trajectory sampling
Suuton-Barto, page 176:

experiment to assess the effect empirically. To isolate the e↵ect of the update distribution,
we used entirely one-step expected tabular updates, as defined by (8.1). In the uniform
case, we cycled through all state–action pairs, updating each in place, and in the on-policy
case we simulated episodes, all starting in the same state, updating each state–action pair
that occurred under the current $\epsilon$-greedy policy ($\epsilon$=0.1). The tasks were undiscounted
episodic tasks, generated randomly as follows. From each of the |S| states, two actions
were possible, each of which resulted in one of b next states, all equally likely, with a
different random selection of b states for each state–action pair. The branching factor, b,
was the same for all state–action pairs. In addition, on all transitions there was a 0.1
probability of transition to the terminal state, ending the episode. The expected reward
on each transition was selected from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.


At any point in the planning process
one can stop and exhaustively compute
$v_{\tilde{\pi}}(s_0)$, the true value of the start state
under the greedy policy, $\tilde{\pi}$, given the current
action-value function Q, as an indication
of how well the agent would do on
a new episode on which it acted greedily
(all the while assuming the model is
correct).

Question: In the first paragraph, authors say the policy used for simulation is $\epsilon$-greedy and in the second paragraph, they are now specifying $\tilde{\pi}$ to be the greedy policy corresponding to the current action-value function Q. However, does not the current action-value function Q correspond to the $\epsilon$-greedy policy?

Note in the picture there are three red lines and three blue lines. Also, please don't paste screenshots full of text. Use text. you could then use pull quotes instead of referring to highlighted bits. The graph seems irrelevant to your question, but including it and referring to colours that are in it makes it appear relevant

I meant the underlined red and blue lines in the text, not red and blue lines in the plot. I updated this in the question.

Thanks. Still needs to be text, not a screenshot please. Screenshots of text from textbooks are not searchable on the site, and less easy for screenreaders to process.

I agree. Now, question statement is in text.

The text is about SARSA, so yes the action values in the Q table are estimates based on-policy, on the $\epsilon$-greedy policy used for learning, with a specific value of $\epsilon$.
However, this in no way constrains how the action values can or should be used to derive any other policy. Deriving a greedy policy from the current action values will typically be an improvement (as per the policy improvement theorem), and also a reasonable gauge of how well the agent has learned the environment so far.
It is fairly common approach in SARSA when using $\epsilon$-greedy policies to decay $\epsilon$, and for both Q-learning and SARSA to evaluate the current greedy policy at snapshots in order to track learning progress without the complication of allowing for exploratory actions.
